# Парсинг формулы. Табличный редактор.

Tags: c++builder, алгоритм, парсер, c++

Есть таблица. В нее записывается либо формула, либо число, либо текст, либо пусто. 
Функция парсера проходить по очереди, по каждому столбцу от начала и до конца. Если, допустим, во второй ячейке записана формула, которая равняется суме первой и последней ячейки. 
Проблема в том, что  последняя ***ячейка еще не просчитаная*** и при парсинге второй ячейки значением последней ячейки является текст/формула, а не простое число. Что можете посоветовать для решения даной проблемы?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Алгоритм известный - вначале пробегаете по всех ячейках и формируете зависимости. Все зависимости складываете в дерево. А там уже просчитываем. Если дерево сложить не получается - значит есть кольцевые зависимости...
Можно сделать немного по другому, без составления дерева. Делаем первый проход по таблице. Если ячейку можно вычислить сразу - вычисляем. Если нет - помечаем зависимости. Потом заходим вторым проходом и пытаемся вычислить помеченные ячейки. В худшем случае кол-во проходов будет равно кол-ву ячеек. Если после очередного прохода вычислили 0 ячеек - значит расчет окончен. Если есть ещё не вычисленные ячейки - есть циклические зависимости. Можно немного ускорить этот метод, если по факту вычисления определенной ячейки проверять, а нет ли у других неразрешенные зависимости.

Можно еще сотворить что то в виде кучи. Если ячейку нельзя вычислить, кладем в кучу. Когда какую то ячейку вычислили - проверяем, нет ли в куче зависимых ячеек.

Comment: Ещё хочется добавить, что если вы пишете Эксель-2, то зависимости стоит хранить в виде двух деревьев (таблиц): ЯчейкаЗависитОт и ЗависящиеОтЯчейки, причем их не вычислять, а хранить и модифицировать. Это, конечно, добавт кода, но быстродействие, особенно на больших таблицах. Естественно за счет расхода памяти))

Comment: Я вот подумал. А что если сделать рекурсивную функцию парсинга. Если формула ссылается на непросчитаную ячейку, тогда функция начинает парсить эту самую ячейку. Тогда не надо будет записывать зависимость. что можете сказать по этому поводу? Рационально ли это?

Comment: Все будет очень красиво до тех пор, пока задача решаемая. Как только появятся циклические ссылки - приплыли. Нужно будет заводить массив использованных ячеек, что бы избежать зацикливания.